# BT and BLE simultaneously on same device

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

We are trying to make an device which can connect to another device running BT and BLE application. Our device is running android kitkat. We are facing following issue.

Once we connect using BT (stream songs over BT) , BLE application running on the same device (that is streaming music) is not detected in BLE scan.

But is detected by other devices (phones in the vicinity).

When we connect using BLE and do some data transfer then connect BT and stream music fromt the same device then both work fine.

Only when we connect to BT first we are not able to detect BLE app running on same device.

Has anyone faced this issue before?

After checking the logs it seems device (Android) does get advertisement packets from BLE app running on another device (iOS) but not the scan response packets. So it keeps waiting for scan response packet. I tried looking for scan request function but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out from debug logs of android stack. Stack was not reporting advertisement it was getting during the BT was streaming to application. It kept waiting for scan response packet. I enabled reporting of this packets in stack and now able to scan and connect to BLE app running iOS while streaming music from same iOS device over BT.

There is one mystery though, am unable to figure out why iPhone does not send scan response when streaming over BT. Will update if I figure it out.